# What is the reason to store subscription into a subscriptions set?

Tags: swift, combine

Combine subscription sample code snippet all store the resulting subscription into the `subscriptions` set

```
private var subscriptions = Set<AnyCancellable>()
```

Why do we need to do it?

```
future
  .sink(receiveCompletion: { print($0) }, receiveValue: { print($0) }) 
  .store(in: &subscriptions)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We usually want to store the subscription *somewhere*, to keep the subscription alive. We often want to keep several subscriptions alive until the enclosing object is destroyed, so it's convenient to store all the subscriptions in a single container.

However, the container does **not** have to be a `Set`! It can be (and usually should be) an `Array`.

`Cancellable` provides **two** `store(in:)` methods:

```
extension Cancellable {
    public func store<C>(in collection: inout C) where C : RangeReplaceableCollection, C.Element == AnyCancellable

    public func store(in set: inout Set<AnyCancellable>)
}
```

(`Array` conforms to `RangeReplaceableCollection`, but `Set` does not, so it needs its own method.)

You have found the one that stores into a `Set`. But do you **need** the behavior of a `Set`? The only reason to store your subscriptions in a `Set` is if you need to efficiently remove a single subscription from the set, and the set may be large. Otherwise, just use an `Array`, like this:

```
class MyObject {

    private var tickets = [AnyCancellable]()

    ...
        future
            .sink(receiveCompletion: { print($0) }, receiveValue: { print($0) }) 
            .store(in: &tickets)
```

I think the reason you often see code that uses a `Set<AnyCancellable>` is because most Swift programmers are much more familiar with `Set` and `Array` than with `RangeReplaceableCollection`. When Xcode offers to autocomplete `store` to take either a `Set` or a `RangeReplaceableCollection`, you're going to pick the `Set` version if you don't know that an `Array` is a `RangeReplaceableCollection`.

Answer (score 2):

`Cancellable` is a protocol provided by Combine.

The subscription code (e.g. publisher, operators, subscriber call chain) return a `Cancellable` object to allow manual cancelation for a subscription and when the object is released from memory, it cancels the whole subscription and release its resources from memory.

To automate the releasing process, we can store multiple subscriptions in `AnyCancellable` collection, so when the collection is about to be deinitialized all subscriptions inside would be canceled and associated resources would be released.

`AnyCancellable` is a type-erased type to allow storing different cancelable types to be stored inside the same collection.

**REFERENCE**

[`store(in:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/anycancellable/store(in:)-3hyxs) stores the type-erasing cancellable instance into a specified set.

Answer (score 1):

If you're only going to need one `AnyCancellable`, you can store it directly.

```swift
private var subscription: AnyCancellable?
```

If you need more than one, a `Set` is generally the way to go, because

1. `AnyCancellable` conforms to `Hashable`.
2. You don't need to store the same `AnyCancellable` multiple times.